# Changing color of some portion of an image

Tags: android, image

Is there any way I can change the color of some portion of an image in Android?

I searched a lot, but I did not find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android.graphics.BitMap.setPixel(x,y,Color)` [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixel%28int,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: X and Y are co-ordinates or what ? If co-ordinates then what co-ordinates.Can you explain plz?

Comment: @AndroidMirza Yes they are co-ordinates. For more details please read the API doc.